# Convert Retrofit Json to Kotlin Map

Tags: kotlin, gson, retrofit2, kotlin-multiplatform

Ok, i have a problem in a Kotlin multiplatform project i am working on at the moment.

I want to get some Currency conversion rates from a api (http://www.floatrates.com/daily/usd.json) and save them in a local Database (Realm).

The problem i am currently facing is, that all the data in the JSON is saved in many many uniquely named objects and not in a Array (these objects all have the same structure).

```
{
"aud": {
    "code": "AUD",
    "alphaCode": "AUD",
    "numericCode": "036",
    "name": "Australian Dollar",
    "rate": 1.5120512400088,
    "date": "Wed, 13 Mar 2024 12:55:07 GMT",
    "inverseRate": 0.66135324884504
},
"cad": {
    "code": "CAD",
    "alphaCode": "CAD",
    "numericCode": "124",
    "name": "Canadian Dollar",
    "rate": 1.3495144747695,
    "date": "Wed, 13 Mar 2024 12:55:07 GMT",
    "inverseRate": 0.74100724274989
},
.
.
 // hundreds more
.
.
"inr": {
    "code": "INR",
    "alphaCode": "INR",
    "numericCode": "356",
    "name": "Indian Rupee",
    "rate": 82.850734958333,
    "date": "Wed, 13 Mar 2024 12:55:07 GMT",
    "inverseRate": 0.012069898963515
},
"jpy": {
    "code": "JPY",
    "alphaCode": "JPY",
    "numericCode": "392",
    "name": "Japanese Yen",
    "rate": 147.78881616883,
    "date": "Wed, 13 Mar 2024 12:55:07 GMT",
    "inverseRate": 0.0067664118701486
}
}
```

I want to save those currencies in some iterable Data structure (for example `Map<String,Currency>` ) with:

```
data class Currency(
   val code: String,
   val alphaCode: String,
   val numericCode: String,
   val name: String,
   val rate: Double,
   val date: String,
   val inverseRate: Double,
 )
```

But i cant get Retrofit to store the data into my map.

If i use the [Json to kotlin class](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9960-json-to-kotlin-class-jsontokotlinclass-) plugin for android studio i can generate a class like this:

```
data class AutoGeneratedResponseDataClass(
   val aed: Aed,
   val afn: Afn,
   val all: All,
   val amd: Amd,
   .
   .
    // hundreds more
   .
   .
   val xpf: Xpf,
   val yer: Yer,
   val zar: Zar,
   val zmw: Zmw,
)
```

with hundereds of other classes like these that are all exactly the same

```
 data class Aed(
    val alphaCode: String,
    val code: String,
    val date: String,
    val inverseRate: Double,
    val name: String,
    val numericCode: String,
    val rate: Double
)
.
.
.
data class Zmw(
    val alphaCode: String,
    val code: String,
    val date: String,
    val inverseRate: Double,
    val name: String,
    val numericCode: String,
    val rate: Double
)
```

I think technically it is possioble to iterate through all fields of an object by using reflection, but and i could change all those class types to one single class, but still, thats not really what i want.

To test if everything is working i have a Dialog that displays the json in form of a string and two buttons, one for a test api that works fine and one for this api that just returns "null", no matter what i try

```
Button(
onClick = { viewModel.getCurrencies() }
) {
    Text(text = "sync currencies")
}
Button(
onClick = { viewModel.getQuotes() }
) {
    Text(text = "sync quotes")
}
Button(
onClick = { viewModel.showDialog = true }
) {
    Text(text = "Show Response")
}
```

[image: thats how it currently looks for testing]

the code for the test api is:

```
//This code works and gets me the desired output
object RetrofitHelperQuotes {
    val baseUrl = "https://quotable.io/"

    fun getInstance(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }
}



interface QuotesApi {
    @GET("/quotes")
    suspend fun getQuotes() : Response<QuoteList>
}
//with 
data class QuoteList(
    val count: Int,
    val lastItemIndex: Int,
    val page: Int,
    val results: List<Result>,
    val totalCount: Int,
    val totalPages: Int
)

data class Result(
    val _id: String,
    val author: String,
    val authorSlug: String,
    val content: String,
    val dateAdded: String,
    val dateModified: String,
    val length: Int,
    val tags: List<String>
)

// and this code in the viewmodel that gets called on button press
@OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
fun getQuotes(){
    val quotesApi = RetrofitHelperQuotes.getInstance().create(QuotesApi::class.java)
    GlobalScope.launch {
        val result = quotesApi.getQuotes()
        if (result != null)
//this is the string that gets stored in the viewModel and gets displayed onscreen when i press the third button
            jsonResponse = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(result.body())
    }
}
```

[image: when i get the quotes from the test api]

and the code for the api i actually want to use is:

```
object RetrofitHelperCurrency {
    val baseUrl = "http://www.floatrates.com/daily/"

    fun getInstance(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }
}

interface CurrencyApi {

    @GET("/usd.json")
    suspend fun getCurrencies() : Response<AutoGeneratedResponseDataClass>

    @GET("/usd.json")
    suspend fun anotherTry() : Response<Map<String,Currency>>

    @GET("/usd.json")
    suspend fun yetAnotherTry() : Response<CurrencyApiResponse>
}
//with
data class CurrencyApiResponse(
    val data: Map<String,Currency>,
)
// and the rest of my classes as described at the top

// and this code in the viewmodel that gets called on button press
@OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
fun getCurrencies(){
    val currencyApi = RetrofitHelperCurrency.getInstance().create(CurrencyApi::class.java)
    GlobalScope.launch {
        val result = currencyApi.getCurrencies()
        if (result != null)
//this is the string that gets stored in the viewModel and gets displayed onscreen when i press the third button
            jsonResponse = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(result.body())

    }
}
```

[image: when i try to get my currencies]

After all that is resolved i want to store the data in a local realm database in case i lose internet connection or something like that, but i am currently stuck at this problem and cant get it to work.

In general i am kina new to programming and this is jsut a "small" learning project for me, but even after googeling my ass off and trying countless things i cant get it to work, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the "/" in front of front of "/usd.json".

Using "/usd.json" results in the following URI: "http://www.floatrates.com/usd.json". But the correct one is "http://www.floatrates.com/daily/usd.json". Tested with wireshark.

The following worked for me to extract the result into a currency list:

```
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import retrofit2.http.GET

interface CurrencyService {
    @GET("usd.json")
    fun getUsd(): Call<Map<String, Currency?>?>?
}

data class Currency(
    val code: String,
    val alphaCode: String,
    val numericCode: String,
    val name: String,
    val rate: Double,
    val date: String,
    val inverseRate: Double
)

fun main() {
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://www.floatrates.com/daily/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    val service = retrofit.create(CurrencyService::class.java)

    val currencyMap = service.getUsd()?.execute()?.body()
    val currencies = currencyMap?.values
    println("repos: ${currencies}")
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was it, i would have never found that, thanks a lot. So basically having http://.../  and then /usd.json removed part of the url and that screwed up everything, so the problem wasn't that it couldn't put the data in the Map, it was that there was no data. Still weird that the other call worked even tho it had the same error.
maybe one more question, whats your reason for using Call<> instead of Response<>.
Should i be doing the same?

Comment: You are welcome. If you use Response you have to call the method from a coroutine context. It would have been more complexe for me to set up. In your case the annotation  @OptIn(...) does this for you I think. So you are fine using Response.